# python max(): how to ignore objects in a list

Tags: python, max

I have a set of lists similar to this one:

```
list = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 5), 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 
    'NA', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 49)]
```

I want to obtain the maximum value in each list without taking in consideration the `'NA'` values.

When I use the max() function I got following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Don't name a variable `list` !

Comment: Use list comprehension or filter to get ride of 'NA'

Comment: There is a difference between a String and a DateTime object. Please do not mix them. Make sure that all the elements in a set should be of same type. OK, you can have all the kinds of items inherited by same parent class, but for comparing two elements either string or a number, both should be strictly of same type, so that the underlying logic compiles it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to exclude items you do not want to compare:

```
import datetime

lst = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 5), 
       'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 49)]

print(max(item for item in lst if item != 'NA'))
```

note that [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list#more-on-lists) is not a good variable in python. you overwrite the built-in `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
new_list = [i for i in list if i != 'NA']
print(max(new_list))
```

By doing this you are creating a new list that will contain only datetime elements, and then you can easily get the maximum value by using the `max()` function.

Or if you don't want to create a new list at all you can just do this:

```
print(max(i for i in list if i != 'NA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take elements from list ignoring `'NA'` and do a `max()`:

```
print(max(x for x in lst if x != 'NA'))
# 1900-01-01 16:49:00
```

Note that I used `lst` instead of `list` because it shadows the built-in [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Answer (score 0):

You may opt to `filter` the wrong elements first:

```
l=[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 5), 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 49)]
max(filter(lambda x: x!= 'NA', l))
```

Comment: There are comprehensions to use instead of `filter` and `lambda` nowadays. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use pandas, you can let a library decide what is error and what is not.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

list1 = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 5), 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 49)]
print(pd.to_datetime(list1, errors='coerce').max().to_pydatetime())
```

returns:

```
1900-01-01 16:49:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
dates_list=[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 5), 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 16, 49)]
# Efficient to use generators rather than producing entire list
print(max((x for x in dates_list if x != 'NA'))) # Notice () instead of []
```

Output:
1900-01-01 16:49:00